# PHP array : simple question about multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i've got a SQL query which returns multiple rows, and i have :

```
$data = array(
    "nom" => $row['nom'] ,
    "prix"   => $row['rapport'],
    "average"   => "$moyenne_ge"
  );
```

**which is perfect, but only if my query returns one row.**

i tried that :

```
$data = array();
$data[$row['nom']]["nom"] = $row['nom'] ;
...
$data[$row['nom']]['average']  = "$moyenne_ge";
```

in order to have :

```
$data[brand1][nom] = brand1
$data[brand1][average] = 150$
$data[brand2][nom] = brand2
$data[brand2][average] = 20$
...
```

but when i do : `json_encode($data)`

i only have the latest JSON object instead of all JSON object from my request as if my array has only one brand instead of 10.

I guess i did something stupid somewhere.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show a little more code? I guess you have a loop somewhere, it would help to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your line:

```
$data = array();
```

Is initializing the array on each iteration of your loop.  You aren't accumulating more than one row of data.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this should work for you:

```
$resource = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
$results = array()

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    $results[$result['brand']] = array(
        'nom' => $result['nom'],
        'prix' => $result['rapport'],
        'average' => $moyenne_ge
    );
)
```

`$results` now contains all the rows from the query indexed by `brand`. Ask in comments if this wasn't what you're looking for.

Comment: i could have work, but it's not, i've found another solution, thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading you right, you should just have to do something like this:

```
$data[] = array(
    "nom" => $row['nom'] ,
    "prix"   => $row['rapport'],
    "average"   => "$moyenne_ge"
);
```

(notice the `[]`)

This should append each array onto $data instead of overwriting the contents.

Comment: thanks, your solution is similar to the previous one and it worked